# Tabulator table inside a JQuery UI dialog opens collapsed

Tags: jquery, tabulator

A Tabulator table put inside a JQuery UI Dialog opens collapsed (no rows visible).  After clicking on a column header the table unrolls.  Am I missing a setting?

This is for an ASP.Net web application, the table is defined as a  within the dialog.

CustomerDataSet below is a JSON array of objects.  The data mapping appears to work fine as the table opens after a click on a table heading.

```
var patTable = new Tabulator("#ptlist-table", {
        selectable: 1,
        data: CustomerDataSet, 
        columns: [
            { title: "Name", field: "name" },
            { title: "Customer ID", field: "id" },
            { title: "Location", field: "location" },
            { title: "Detail", field: "detail" },
            { title: "Order date/time", field: "timestamp" },
        ],
    });

$("#dialog-id").dialog("open");  // The table shows inside the dialog.
```

I expect the table to show in full upon the dialog opening.
Instead, the table shows collapsed until I click on a column heading.

Answer (score 1):

If the element you are initializing Tabulator with is initially hidden, you will have to call `patTable.redraw(true)` after it is shown.  This is because when an element is hidden, JavaScript returns 0 for width and height.

So, when Tabulator is initialized, all the calculations it does for widths and heights for its internal elements will be incorrect and the table won't render as you expect.  There are many other JS workarounds for this scenario if you wish to research it, but I suggest just asking Tabulator to redraw/re-render itself.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve it by a programmatic click on a table's column header when the dialog opens:

myDialog = $("#dialog-id").dialog({
    ...
    ...
        open: function () {
            $("#ptlist-table").find(".tabulator-col").first().click();
        }, 
   ...